# How to print scientific notation number into same scale

Tags: python, numpy

I want to print scientific notation number with same scale in python. For example I have different numbers `(1e-6, 3e-7, 5e-7, 4e-8)`so now I want to print all these numbers with `e-6` notation `(1e-6, 0.3e-6, 0.5e-6, 0.04e-6)`. So how can I print it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematically, tacking on `e-6` is the same as multiplying by `1e-6`, right?

So, you've got a number `x`, and you want to know what `y` to use such that `y * 1e-6 == x`.

So, just multiply by 1e6, render that in non-exponential format, then tack on `e-6` as a string:

```
def e6(x):
  return '%fe-6' % (1e6 * x,)
```

Answer (score 1):

using `log10`:

```
In [64]: lis= (1e-6, 3e-7, 5e-7, 4e-8)

In [65]: import math

In [66]: for x in lis:
    exp=math.floor(math.log10(x))
    num=x/10**exp              
    print "{0}e-6".format(num*10**(exp+6))
   ....:     
   ....:     
1.0e-6
0.3e-6
0.5e-6
0.04e-6
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're using numpy, you should definitely take a look at the [`np.set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) function, in particular its `formatter` argument that takes a dictionary like `{'float': formatting_function}`. Use the most appropriate formatting function for your particular case.